# How can I recover my ext4 drives on Debian?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, debian

I have been using OMV on a Raspberry Pi as a NAS for a while and I realised that the Rpi and therefore the drives were under-powered. To solve this I bought a USB hub, removed the drives and plugged them into this. When I restarted the pi, I could no longer find the drives despite them showing up on `dmesg`.

Plugging them back into the main USB ports I can see one of them as `sda` in `/dev` and with `lsblk` without any partitions but I can't open it, find either in `/dev/disk` or with `fdisk -l`. OMV sees the same one too but only the disk not the file-system.

I have tried everything that I can find online and I really need help with it.